# Parent - children chain messed up after exporting to FBX

Tags: export, parent, .fbx

Blender 2.82a. I have the following setup (see the 1st picture):

- **Cube** at position 0,0,0
- **Cube.001** (child of **Cube**) at position 0,0,3
- **Cube.002** (child of **Cube.001" - grandchild) - on position 3,0,3

When I export to FBX, the position of **Cube.002** unexpectedly changes and gets position of (3,-3,3) and is also rotated (see the 2nd picture).

Anybody can explain what's going on?

*Additional note:* I need to export to FBX so I can use it in a game. I don't need it to import back to Blender (I did it though to simplify the case). The problem is visible in any other program which can open FBX.

[image: Setup before export]
[image: Setup imported from FBX]

Comment: I've just found this problem is caused by "Apply Transform" option, but still don't know how to prevent it.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMHJK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMHJK.png) try this settings and check the results

Comment: linking same problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272119/animations-play-differently-when-exported

Comment: I faced the same problem, did you manage to solve it?