# Animations play differently when exported as FBX

Tags: animation

I'm a big newbie when it comes to animation in Blender and 3D in general.

I have created 3 separate objects, each with a different animation. When I export all 3 objects as an FBX file, they all play one animation which was supposed to be assigned to just one of the objects (the other 2 should be playing completely different animations!).

Need some advice

[image]

Comment: You may want to edit your question to name your destination import software.  Are you exporting to FBX and then importing back into blender?   If something else, try re-importing into a new blender session to see if a blender "export/import round trip" is successful.  Also, try to use https://blend-exchange.com/ to include a link to your blender file.

Comment: @james_t i can confirm this when i import fbx back to blender itself. the parent cube is rotating even though it didnt rotate in the original blend file.

Comment: either what you are doing is not supported or it's a bug. i think you should give up on using your setup with fbx. someone else had the same problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175863/parent-children-chain-messed-up-after-exporting-to-fbx most likely a bug.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you for helping out, perhaps an older version of Blender might behave differently so I'll check it out :)

Comment: @NunoDuarte hey no problem. it's very unlikely though that it works in older versions. I'm quite sure it cannot be fixed. sorry.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie -- agreed, see https://developer.blender.org/T51807.  merges     T98567: innacurate animation upon export / re-import FBX Animation

Comment: on another note try to read the comments in this report https://developer.blender.org/T65768 maybe this can help with multiple object animations