# Exporting Animation to FBX Issues

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

Just looking for some advicee - I'm looking to export this scene as an FBX with each fish (50 of) following it's own animation. Every time I export it, the fish compact into one animation within the fbx instead of their own independent 50 individual animations. The models seem to incorporate just one of the 50 animations instead of their own respective ones. Any help is appreciated!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMZSjkbK9pYgbZ4EgzsY2lpVQiDddfEW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please find a zip folder with the blender file and textures attached :)

Comment: fbx animations are problematic. don't use fbx. similar issue here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272119/animations-play-differently-when-exported?noredirect=1#comment466497_272119

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie is there a format you would recommend? I'm trying to import the asset into unity / omniverse

Comment: on another note try to read the comments in this report https://developer.blender.org/T65768 maybe this can help with multiple object animations