# How to export Animation data from Blender

Tags: animation, export, camera, import, .fbx

I‘ve been trying to export my animated camera from Blender to Houdini but it seems not to work. If I export the Camera with baked animation and then import it into Houdini I get a camera with keyframes that have the same values. If I import it back to blender only the camera will be imported but no animation or keyframes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! what format did u export to? also try other formats.

Comment: I exported as .fbx because I saw other people saying that this worked for them…

Comment: I tried using an alembic file this worked but it would be nice to know what I did wrong when exporting as fbx

Comment: i noticed fbx is buggy, you can try a simple cube and doing some simple rotation animations and see for yourself. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272119/animations-play-differently-when-exported-as-fbx

Comment: This works. Is this a problem of the format or Blender?